# Firebase Cloud Firestore - What happens if my app reached the maximum document writes/reads per day?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, billing

I use firebase cloud firestore (Spark Plan, the free plan) to store the data of my app.

The plan includes 20K Document Writes, Reads and deletes per day.

**Let's assume that the app reached 20K document reads one day, My question is: What will happen ?**

- Will the Firestore not receive any requests until I upgrade the current plan ?
- Will it not receive any requests until the end of the day, and everything will be ok on the next day (I get new 20K reads) ?
- Will it continue receiving the requests without any problems and adding charges on my account, then I get surprised that I have to pay $1000 for these requests ?
- Will the account get suspended or blocked ?

I searched a lot everywhere but can't seem to find a clear and straightforward answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Will the Firestore not receive any requests until I upgrade the current plan ?

- Quotas are applied daily and resets every day around midnight Pacific time. You shall continue from next day.

> Will it not receive any requests until the end of the day, and everything will be ok on the next day (I get new 20K reads) ?

- YES, requests above the free quota limit will get rejected. AFIK, with error - RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded.
- YES, you will get new 20k FREE reads for the day

> Will it continue receiving the requests without any problems and adding charges on my account, then I get surprised that I have to pay $1000 for these requests ?

- Definitely NO.

> Will the account get suspended or blocked ?

- NO.

---

For quota and limit - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas.

To check your project usage, open the Cloud Firestore [Usage tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/firestore/usage) in the Firebase console