# What will happen if my spark plan of cloud firestore exceeds it's limit and I don't upgrade my plan?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently **cloud firestore spark or free plan** provides **20k writes/day**, **50k reads/day**, **20k deletes/day**.

What will happen if my spark plan of cloud firestore exceeds it's limit and I don't upgrade my plan?

Will my apps start using firestore offline database or will my account/project get disabled?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65873056/firebase-cloud-firestore-what-happens-if-my-app-reached-the-maximum-document-w

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any read/write/delete operation will return a `'resource-exhausted'` error if you have utilized your free quota for the day. You'll have to wait until it resets.

> Quotas are applied daily and reset around midnight Pacific time.

Comment: Will my app use offline firestore database or will it also be blocked?

Comment: @RawnakYazdani "By default, get() attempts to provide up-to-date data when possible by waiting for data from the server, but it may return cached data or fail if you are offline and the server cannot be reached. This behavior can be altered via the Source parameter." so it may fail but you can try forcing the source to cache.